# RSpec Controller test failing for text on screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have an index view with "Settings" in an h1 element.

```
<div id="settings-main-container">
  <div id="settings-main-title">
    <h1 id="settings-title">Settings</h1>
  </div>
  <%=link_to admin_clients_index_path do%>
    <div class="settings-button">
      Select Active Client
    </div>
 <%end%>
 <%=link_to admin_settings_assign_users_to_clients_index_path do%>
    <div class="settings-button">
        Assign Users to Clients
    </div>
 <%end%>
 <%=link_to destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete do%>
   <div class="settings-button">
     Logout
   </div>
 <%end%>
</div>
```

I have my test set up

```
describe "GET index" do
  render_views
  ...

  it "should have text on the screen" do
    get :index
    response.should have_text("Settings")
  end
end
```

I keep getting the error

```
Failure/Error: response.should have_text("Settings")
   expected to find text "Settings" in "#"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `response.body.should have_text`??

Comment: That was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response` holds stuff like headers, response code, and response body. So if you want to check for the rendered views - you should check `response.body`:

```
response.body.should have_text("Settings")
```